# Which clue KSI have to make Transformer : Transformers Age of Extinction

Tags: transformers, age-of-extinction

As I watch the *Transformers Age of Extinction*. In the Movie the KSI owner Joshua Joyce said that "Now they can create the Transformer". and in the movie we can see that they have made it's own Transformer.

Which clue or Technique KSI have to make AutoBots or Transformer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explained at [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformers:_Age_of_Extinction)

> Infiltrating KSI’s headquarters in Chicago, Cade discovers the murdered Autobots are being melted down and their bodies used for making manmade Transformer drones. Joshua Joyce, the ambitious company CEO, is in league with Attinger to revolutionise global defences and improve human society using the Seed. He has also **used the captured Brains and Megatron’s head to create prototype Transformer soldiers** Galvatron and Stinger